# Docker machine create another client side only config

Tags: docker-machine, multi-user

I have just created (or provisioned is maybe the correct word) a Docker Engine instance using Docker Machine. It was almost painless. ;-)

Because of the side effects of `docker-machine create --driver generic ...` we cannot have multiple users of the machine run this since it will

1. Turn of Docker Engine on that machine.
2. Cause potential problems with a production environment.

How can we run only the client side part of `docker-machine create --driver generic ...`? That is, create a configuration, and install the certificates? Is there a way or should we just copy the folder `~/.docker/machine/machines/*` folders around and make changes to the json data adapted for the different administrators?